# power-down persistent storage in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to store some simple data - an alarm time and some booleans - in a way that survives device power off. I've been trying with sharedPreferences, but the data gets lost when I reboot the phone (it survives okay if the phone stays on).

I've read the docs and scanned this site as well as others, but I can't find a definitive answer to whether sharedPreferences are this persistent.

I could store the values using SqlLite or a file, but I just wanted to know if I'm maybe doing something wrong before I write any unnecessary code.

Here are some code snippets:

```
public static final String ALARM_PREFERENCES = "AlarmPrefs";
public static final String ALARM_PREFERENCES_VIBRATE = "AlarmVibrate"; // Boolean

...

prefs = getSharedPreferences(ALARM_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

...

mVibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(ALARM_PREFERENCES_VIBRATE,mVibrate.isChecked());
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Those preferences should survice power down. Can you post the code that reads them back in?

Comment: Haha - my bad. I'd forgotten that bit! It's been a long day destroying braincells with Coldfusion. Thanks for the slap on the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedPreferences are persistent across phone boots. Your code for saving the prefs looks ok too.

Comment: Thanks - you're right. See my comment above. You get the prize for making the only definitive statement I've yet seen on how persistent shared prefs are.